# How to set root user password for mysql while installing erpnext?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, erpnext

I am installing Erpnext in my ubuntu 18.04 Lts. I want to know how to set password for MySql root user.

I am installing erpnext in my ubuntu 18.04 LTS. while running the command - 'sudo bench new-site site4.local' for creating a new frappe site, it is asking for - 'MySQL root password':

I have tried - `sudo mysql --user=root mysql' but it is giving output as- mysql: unknown variable 'pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
```

Comment: I think you will find a password parameter in here : `sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

Comment: It is giving output as -> cat: –: No such file or directory.

Comment: Path for my configuration file is as follows - sudo cat  /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: How to set  password for root here?

Comment: Edit this file and set your desired password at the password variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to set root password if not set already. While setting root password check if password **plugin** is set to mysql_native_password or not. If password **plugin** is set to unix_socket change it to mysql_native_password. unix_socket ignore passwords and allow the corresponding Unix user in without a password check. To change plugin type follow below command:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', 
      Password = PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE User = 'root';
flush privileges;
quit;
```

Replace NEWPASSWORD with your password